# How I do properly import serial data from arduino using pycharm

Tags: python, matplotlib, arduino, pycharm

I am newbie in python.
After I installed python 3.8 latest version, libraries ...etc 
Pycharm IDE, and for every time you create project you have to install packages so your code look nice with no red line under.
after I spent hours trying to find whats going on, Error, visual studio  ++14 and not 15 or 19.

The code line, `import serial` doesn't seem recognized by pycharm or by python.
I have read many people having the same problem but few were successful to solve, other are still not. 
My Problem is that I need to plot data from arduino using python over serial.
Anyone have an idea how to solve the `import serial` not working?

The code implemented:

```
import serial                       , error    
import numpy as np                package not found but managed to install it and have to install it again  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt     
%matplotlib qt

ser = serial.Serial('COM4',9600)   Syntax error
```

Just tried to install matplotlib package, I got this error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cython'
```

An hour ago did work just fine downloading the package. 
Any recommendation for another python IDE than pycharm ?

Answer (score 0):

U can use anaconda navigator. It comes with many inbuilt libraries such as pandas numpy matlab etc according to me it is best to use anaconda navigator in which u can either use spyder ide or jyputer notebook do upvode if u found helpful

Comment: Thank you .  I did download anaconda as you mentioned. I received the same error message.   MouduleNotfound

Comment: Have u checked that the desired libraries ar installed in you conda navigator because some time it requires to install it from conda library in the app itself .and if the problem continues try using online python console repl.it

Comment: libraries installed both using windows terminal running the code pip install xxxxxx and in the IDE package downloader. Visual studio maker 2019 is also installed. still no luck to write the correct syntax.. NameError

Comment: Its better to try on online python console ones.